# How to interact with vertex shader in react three fiber?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm new to React Three Fiber and would like to add some physics to a particle shader, like when the mouse approaches the particles they move away in the opposite direction, but when the mouse pointer moves away from the particle they return to its original position.
I would like the movement of physics to look like a bubble effect.

Should I create a custom vertex shader to achieve this effect?

Comment: This is quite... complex question. You can check my answer about particles here to catch some directions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77568692/using-react-three-fibers-text-component-to-create-a-beautifully-animated-text-c/77572085#77572085 part about R3F is exactly what you asking for (excluding mouse move).  Main idea is, create particles >Points / shader material > connect with mouse move. That will be helpful as well for you https://blog.maximeheckel.com/posts/the-magical-world-of-particles-with-react-three-fiber-and-shaders/

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz I gonna check it