# Using React Three Fibers Text component to create a beautifully animated Text, consisting of PARTICLES?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have been suffering a lot and trying a lot of things, however, I still failed :( I want to create a beautiful Text, which only consists of 1000s of moving particles (custom amount that I can choose). How can this be done?
As an example, please check this Vanilla JavaScript version out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2F2t1RJoGt8&t=30s
[image]
Thanks a lot for any ideas and details about a potential implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it (plain 3js)

1. By points material
2. By shader material

I have some code for you, when I was experimenting with that.

Assuming that you have model (for instance, some Text):
1.

```
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();

gltfLoader.load("CC.glb", (glb) => {
  cc = glb.scene.children[0];
  const pointsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: 0.02,
    color: new THREE.Color(0x343355),
  cc = new THREE.Points(cc.geometry, pointsMaterial);
  cc.rotation.set(1.08, 0, 0);
  cc.position.set(0.84, -0.54, -1);
  scene.add(cc);
});
```

2. 

```
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
const particlesShader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  // transparent: true,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  vertexShader: particlesVertex,
  fragmentShader: particlesFragment,
});


gltfLoader.load("CC.glb", (glb) => {
  const cc = glb.scene.children[0];
  cc.rotation.set(1.08, 0, 0);
  cc.position.set(0.84, -0.54, -1);

  scene.add(cc);

  const geometry = cc.geometry.clone();
  const points = new THREE.Points(geometry, particlesShader);
  scene.add(points);
});
```

Vetex

```
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = 2.0;
    vColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment

```
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

If you asking about R3F, I working for something now with particles, I didnt make any researching about Text/or Drei helper. But maybe you will catch some idea from my project.
I need to make shape (equilateral triangle) in JS so probably similar stuff to tutorial which you show above.

```
const beltMaterial = useRef();
  const modelRef = useRef();

  const count = 15000;

  const particlesPosition = useMemo(() => {
    const positions = new Float32Array(count * 3);
    function generateTriangleCoordinates(size) {
      const halfSize = size / 2;
      const vertices = [
        [0, halfSize, 0],
        [-halfSize, -halfSize, 0],
        [halfSize, -halfSize, 0],
      ];
      const edges = [
        [0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 0],
      ];
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const edgeIndex = i % edges.length;
        const [startIndex, endIndex] = edges[edgeIndex];
        const t = Math.random();
        const [startX, startY, startZ] = vertices[startIndex];
        const [endX, endY, endZ] = vertices[endIndex];
        positions.set(
          [
            startX + t * (endX - startX),
            startY + t * (endY - startY),
            startZ + t * (endZ - startZ),
          ],
          i * 3
        );
      }
      return positions;
    }
    const triangleSize = 3.0;
    generateTriangleCoordinates(triangleSize);
    return positions;
  }, [count]);

return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <points
        ref={modelRef}
        position={[0, 0, 10]}
        scale={[-12, 9, -1]}
        rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
      >
        <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
          <bufferAttribute
            attach="attributes-position"
            count={particlesPosition.length / 3}
            array={particlesPosition}
            itemSize={3}
          />
        </bufferGeometry>

        <beltMaterial
          ref={beltMaterial}
          // depthTest={false}
          alphaTest={0.001}
          sizeAttenuation={true}
          // side={THREE.DoubleSide}
          // transparent={true}
          depthWrite={false}
          blending={THREE.AdditiveBlending}
        />
      </points>
    </group>
  );
```